# HelveticaNeueThn font not support in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I had set HelveticaNeueThn font in my project.HelveticaNeueThn font working well in iOS 7.But it will not support When i run the same font in iOS 6 .It showing bold font instead of HelveticaNeueThn.

My question is, is it possible to set HelveticaNeueThn in iOS 6.

Comment: `HelveticaNeue-Thin` is available from iOS 7 and up. For a good overview of available font check out http://www.iosfonts.com/

Comment: and what is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes iOS 6 not supports "HelveticaNeue-Thin" font.It is available From iOS 7.
So, Your app should use a default iOS 6 font when run under iOS 6.

Comment: there have any way to set HelveticaNeueThn in coding for ios 6.

Comment: Add custom font for it.
 
Download “HelveticaNeue-Thin” font From here :
http://mexicoxport.com/development/fonts/
  
You have to follow this link to add custom font in your app: 
http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: Keep in mind that Helvetica Neue is NOT a free font! You need to buy a [license](http://www.linotype.com/1266/NeueHelvetica-family.html?site=valuepacks) to use it.

Comment: @JustSid thanx for this important info.